# Loop while array has element with specific value

Tags: python

let say I have list of devices and I need to check their statuses before script can continue. In simple way it can look like this:

```
devices = {
    'dev1': {'ready':False, ...},
    'dev2': {'ready':False, ...},
    'dev3': {'ready':False, ...}
}

while /exists device with 'ready' == False/:
    ... some code scanning for devices ...
    if /device ready/:
        devices[devX]['ready'] = True
```

I can't figure it out how should condition in while statement looks like.

The closest solution which I found was:

```
len([d for d in devices if d['ready'] == True]) > 0
```

But it gives me TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

Can you please advise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `for d in devices` returns only the keys of the dict. Change your line to

```
len([d for d, v in devices.items() if v['ready'] == True]) > 0
```

Comment: I was so close ;) Thanks, that also do the job!

Answer (score 4):

In your code you have `d` iterating through each key in devices (not each value). That's why `d['ready']` doesn't work: `d` is a string, like `'dev1'`. You can iterate the values using [`devices.values()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values).

If you want to check if any value in your `devices` dict is ready, you could use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

```
if any(x['ready'] for x in devices.values()):
```

If you want to check if they are all ready, you could use [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all):

```
if all(x['ready'] for x in devices.values()):
```

Comment: Great! It helped a lot! Thanks